# R floating point number precision being lost on coversion from character

Tags: r, casting, numeric

I have a large floating point number as a character like so

```
  x<-"5374761693.91823";
```

On doing

```
 as.numeric(x);
```

I get the following output

```
   5374761694
```

I would like to preserve the floating point nature of the number while casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `digits` argument in `print` to see the actual number:

```
> print(as.numeric(x), digits=15)
[1] 5374761693.91823
```

`options` is another alternative:

```
> options(digits=16)
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 5374761693.91823

> # assignments
> options(digits=16)
> y <- as.numeric(x)
> y
[1] 5374761693.91823

z <- print(as.numeric(x), digits=15)
z
```

Comment: what about assignment ?